# How to reduce title bar height?

Tags: gala

On my Elementary OS Freya dconf Editor have less height than others applications (for example atom or chromium) and I prefer this smaller appearance. I wonder what css or xml file I have to edit in order to achieve it, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio Code, except that I'm using Loki, but I don't see why it won't work with Freya.

Go to `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0` and add this inside `apps.css` :

```
.header-bar.default-decoration {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Just play with the padding to get the desired height.

Do not forget to restart Gala, after you've edited the file.
**Not sure why, but some apps such as Terminal and File Manager won't get affected.**

*Source : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1518845#p1518845*

---

**UPDATE**

This trick doesn't work with GTK3.18+, so if you're using 3.19 or 3.20, please use this css code instead.

```
/* shrink headerbars */
headerbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    padding-left: 2px; /* same as childrens vertical margins for nicer proportions */
    padding-right: 2px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 0px; /* same as headerbar side padding for nicer proportions */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* shrink ssd titlebars */
.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; /* let the entry and button drive the titlebar size */
    padding: 0px
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 0px; /* tweak these two props to reduce button size */
    min-width: 0px;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    min-height: 0;
}

window.ssd headerbar.titlebar button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Source : https://ogbe.net/blog/gnome_titles.html & https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/46gplm/does_anyone_know_how_to_decrease_titlebar_height/?sort=old

Comment: I have a few questions. In gtk-3.0 directory are several

Comment: Ooops sorry, totally forgot to say which file to edit... :)
It's the 'apps.css' file

Comment: `sudo vim /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`
Added this snippet at the beginning of this file and saved it.
Restarted Gala by `sudo service lightdm restart`
Opened Atom, Firefox, dconf - there are no changes, maybe I've something missed? PS. Even added !important  - just for a good measure, but it didn't the trick :(

Comment: With GTK3.18+ this doesn't work, could you tell me which version you're using by typing this command : `dpkg -s libgtk-3-0 | grep '^Version'`

Comment: `Version: 3.14.15-0ubuntu1~14.04~ricotz1` (since I'm using Freya I believe it's impossible to upgrade GTK further without crashing). I wonder why very first code failed, though. Maybe it requires at least 3.16 or something...

Comment: Really strange indeed... did you try the second piece of code?

Comment: Yep, but it does nothing, since gtk version on which I am is 3.14. Probably it's time to consider migration to Loki.

Comment: Hmm... I don't really what's going on, sorry.
Since I'm not an expert of GTK or UNIX, hope someone with knowledge will answer.